# Using python to plot perpendicular vectors upon a 2D circle

Tags: python, matplotlib

In my code I'm assuming that the 2D circle is a planet similar to Earth but blue. I want to plot the two vectors a_h and a_r perpendicular to each other on the edge of the blue circle but I'm not sure how to place the perpendicular vectors a_h and a_r on the top or bottom of the circle.[What I want to plot in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgJwX.jpg)[not circular?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulV9p.png)[quiver plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYSbV.png)

Here's the code I'm using:

```
    # Importing modules
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


    g=9.81
    Mmoon=7.3477e22 #mass of Moon
    Mearth=5.972e24 #mass of Earth

    R_min=356.5e6 #Perigee
    R_max=406.7e6 #Apogee
    R_avg = 0.5*(R_min + R_max)
    r = 6.3781e6 #radius of Earth

    theta=np.linspace(-1*np.pi,1*np.pi,180)

    a_R=3*g*(Mmoon/Mearth)*((r/(R_avg))**3)*np.cos(theta)   
    #acceleration vector

    a_h=3*g*(Mmoon/Mearth)*((r/(R_avg))**3)*np.cos(theta)*np.sin(theta)         
    #tangential acceleration vector
    a_r=3*g*(Mmoon/Mearth)*((r/(R_avg))**3)*np.cos(theta)*np.cos(theta)         
    #perpendicular acceleration vector

    plt.quiver([0,0 ], [0,0], [2,-2], [-4, -2], angles='xy',         
    scale_units='xy', scale=1)
    plt.xlim(-10,10)
    plt.ylim(-10,10)

    earth = plt.Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.2, color='blue')  # (x_pos, y_pos), rad

    fig, ax = plt.subplots() # note we must use plt.subplots, not 
    plt.subplot
    #(or if you have an existing figure)
    fig = plt.gcf()
    ax = fig.gca()
    ax.add_artist(earth)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Why did you edit the `Circle` out? Using a scatter this will be really hard, because you first would need to know how large 500 points are in data units to display your arrows there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense not to use a scatter here, because this would require to calculate the number of points that scatter has in data units. Instead using a circle is fine.

The arrows are placed at a position according to the moon orbit `R_avg`. Their length is arbitrary here, but of course you may change it to whatever you like.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

R_min=356.5e6 #Perigee
R_max=406.7e6 #Apogee
R_avg = 0.5*(R_min + R_max)
r = 6.3781e6 #radius of Earth

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect("equal")
i = 0

# create arrows on moon orbit, both one orbit radius in length to both directions
ax.quiver([0,0], [R_avg,R_avg], [1,0], [0, 1], angles='xy',         
          scale_units='xy', scale=1./R_avg)

# create earth and moon orbit
earth = plt.Circle((0,0),r)
orbit = plt.Circle((0,0),R_avg, fill=False, color="crimson")
ax.add_patch(earth)
ax.add_patch(orbit)
ax.autoscale_view()
ax.margins(1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The `Circle` command does nothing in your code. Why not just use a `scatter` circular marker?

```
plt.scatter(0., 0., 100, color='blue')
```

Comment: This is rather unhelpful as answer, if you don't tell the questioner how many points the earth' diameter is.